# Python-Function object creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, object

As I understand from a book that function in Python is nothing but object of Function class. I have some doubts as below:

1.When this object gets created? At the time we define function or at the time we call a function?

2.If it is getting created at the time we define a function, then will it not be a waste of memory if we do not call that function anywhere in program ?

Looking for detail answer.

Comment: 1) when you define the function 2) if you define a function that you never plan to call? Yes, I would say that is a waste. Although, probably extremely minor, even on modest hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As soon as you define a function or method (which is nothing but a bound function), Python creates a Function instance. This happens when your code is run for the first time.
2. Yes, it is a "waste" of memory, but consider how much memory that is compared to big arrays, binary files etc. Python is definitely not the most performant or resource-light language/interpreter, but it saves you lots of time on writing code (because your write less) and caring about optimisation (you usually don't). I mean seriously, what do a few KB in file size matter nowadays? Surely the loss in value is less than a minute of your attention.

   The reason those unused functions can't be optimised away is that they might be used later on in the same script or by other scripts.